# Accessing python runner file in AWS EKS as in local://

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-eks

In my spark-submit to eks cluster, I use the standard code to submit to the cluster as below:

```
CODE_DIRECTORY="/home/hduser/dba/bin/python"
```

Then this is the spark-submit job

```
spark-submit --verbose \
   --master k8s://$KUBERNETES_MASTER_IP:443 \
   --deploy-mode cluster \
   --name sparkOnEks \
   --py-files local://$CODE_DIRECTORY/spark_on_eks.zip \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.namespace=$NAMESPACE \
   --conf spark.network.timeout=300 \
   --conf spark.executor.instances=$NEXEC \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.allocation.batch.size=3 \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.allocation.batch.delay=1 \
   --conf spark.driver.cores=2 \
   --conf spark.executor.cores=2 \
   --conf spark.driver.memory=8092m \
   --conf spark.executor.memory=8092m \
   --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true \
   --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.shuffleTracking.enabled=true \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.container.image=${IMAGEDRIVER} \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.container.image=${IMAGEDRIVER} \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.driver.serviceAccountName=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.driver.pod.name=$SPARK_DRIVER_NAME  \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.executor.pod.name=$SPARK_EXECUTOR_NAME  \
   --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true" \
   --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="-Dio.netty.tryReflectionSetAccessible=true" \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.subdmission.caCertFile=$K8S_CACERT  \
   --conf spark.kubernetes.authenticate.submission.oauthTokenFile=$K8S_TOKEN  \
   local:///home/hduser/dba/bin/python/spark_on_eks/src/${APPLICATION}
```

This spark-submit is from EC2 node.  `${APPLICATION}="RandomDataBigQuery.py"`

The problem seems to be that eks cannot read python file from local:///

```
local:///home/hduser/dba/bin/python/spark_on_eks/src/${APPLICATION}
```

The job fails with

```
     container started at: 2023-04-11T23:07:19Z
     container finished at: 2023-04-11T23:07:24Z
     exit code: 2
     termination reason: Error
23/04/11 23:07:26 INFO LoggingPodStatusWatcherImpl: Application sparkOnEks with submission ID spark:driver-pod finished
```

When I look at the logs `kubectl logs driver-pod -n spark`, I see below

```
    + CMD=("$SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit" --conf "spark.driver.bindAddress=$SPARK_DRIVER_BIND_ADDRESS" --deploy-mode client "$@")
    + exec /usr/bin/tini -s -- /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit --conf spark.driver.bindAddress=192.168.39.251 --deploy-mode client --properties-file /opt/spark/conf/spark.properties --class org.apache.spark.deploy.PythonRunner local:///home/hduser/dba/bin/python/spark_on_eks/src/RandomDataBigQuery.py
    23/04/11 23:07:23 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
    /usr/bin/python3: can't open file '/home/hduser/dba/bin/python/spark_on_eks/src/RandomDataBigQuery.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).

It says  can't open file '/home/hduser/dba/bin/python/spark_on_eks/src/RandomDataBigQuery.py': 

    [Errno 2] No such file or directory but it is there!


ls -l /home/hduser/dba/bin/python/spark_on_eks/src/RandomDataBigQuery.py
    -rw-rw-rw- 1 hduser hadoop 5060 Mar 18 14:16 /home/hduser/dba/bin/python/spark_on_eks/src/RandomDataBigQuery.py

So not sure what is going on.  Does it expect file to be loaded to hdfs directory, Can I use s3 storage for this purpose?
```

Comment: I have a suspicion that spark is looking inside the docker image for that file?